# Composer doesn't clone git repo with prefer-source

Tags: windows, git, composer-php

I did reinstall my git added to my PATH. When I try to install my dependencies with composer (with `--prefer-source`) It doesn't clone with the `.git` folder. It does add the `--no-checkout` flag to the clones or just download the zips. I did clean the composer cache several times also manually. Composer is also up2date. But I don't know why my composer doesn't clone the repo with `.git` folder.

**EDIT (SOLUTION)**

The problem seems that it takes too long to clone the repo and my PHP installation run into a PHP `max_execution_timeout` and then composer fallback to zip. I did install all dependencies remove the one I needed to clone and did run git clone myrepo.git manually.

Comment: did you try to remove the `vendor` folder and reinstall your dependencies with `composer install --prefer-source`?

Comment: was also my first thought to remove the whole vendor and clean the composer cache. and yes I added the --prefer-source flag

Comment: did found the problem and add it to EDIT

Comment: Now I wonder why there is a `max_execution_timeout` setting for the command line PHP. This usually is only enabled for the webserver PHP.

Comment: @Sven its a xampp installation don't know if there exists an own cli config.